Is this correct "libvmaf" initialization code?
 VmafConfiguration vmafCfg = {};
 vmafCfg.log_level = VMAF_LOG_LEVEL_ERROR;

 vmaf_init(&handle->vmafCtx, vmafCfg);
 VmafCudaConfiguration cudaCfg = {};
 cudaCfg.cu_ctx = cuCtx;

 vmaf_cuda_state_init(&handle->vmafState, cudaCfg);
 vmaf_cuda_import_state(handle->vmafCtx, handle->vmafState);

 VmafCudaPictureConfiguration cudaPicCfg = {};
 cudaPicCfg.pic_params.w = picWidth;
 cudaPicCfg.pic_params.h = picHeight;
 cudaPicCfg.pic_params.bpc = bitDepth;
 cudaPicCfg.pic_params.pix_fmt = VMAF_PIX_FMT_YUV400P;
 cudaPicCfg.pic_prealloc_method = VMAF_CUDA_PICTURE_PREALLOCATION_METHOD_DEVICE;

 vmaf_cuda_preallocate_pictures(handle->vmafCtx, cudaPicCfg);

 VmafModelConfig modelCfg = {};

 if (vmafModelPath.empty())
 {
   vmaf_model_load(&handle->vmafModel, &modelCfg, "vmaf_v0.6.1");
 }
 else
 {
   vmaf_model_load_from_path(&handle->vmafModel, &modelCfg, ipar.vmafModelPath.c_str());
 }
 vmaf_use_features_from_model_(handle->vmafCtx, handle->vmafModel);

I set the chroma format to 400 because VMAF is said to measure the score using only the luma component. However, there is a discrepancy compared to the VMAF scores measured using FFmpeg's libvmaf, so I'm not sure if I've implemented it correctly.

Are you asking this question because you're not in a position to compile and run the code, or is there an actual problem that you think is caused by your code? If the latter, edit your question with expected and actual outcomes.
